# Dynamics CRM 2011 500GB SQL Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I installed Dynamics CRM 2011 like 5 month ago and It was working flawlessly , but now I got an error that the server is full of storage I gave the server 1TB of storage. The CRM SQL Database is using 430 GB which is very big for 5 month ! What can be possibly wrong . Auditing is only using 5 GB this is what the auditing page in CRM listed.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071473/how-to-measure-table-size-in-gb-in-a-table-in-sql

Comment: @Daryl yes it didn't resolve my problem

Comment: Did it tell you what database tables were taking up the majority of memory?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your sql log files are really getting big.
I suggest youll read about shrinking the sql log files:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/patricg/archive/2007/10/03/sql-server-tips-n-2-best-practices-for-shrinking-t-log-files-and-database-files.aspx