# what is the difference between a mul-dim array of mul-dim objects and an array of one higher dim that contains only one-dim objects

Tags: c++, c, opencv

i read in (Learning OpenCV) topic about array of point and i dont understand difference
between a multidimensional array (or matrix) of multidimensional objects and an
array of one higher dimension that contains only one-dimensional objects.

Comment: If you could provide an example type for the two cases, I may understand your question.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242705/performance-of-2-dimensional-array-vs-1-dimensional-array

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: give me example pleace

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, a multidimensional array is simply an array of arrays.

On the other hand, there are a lot of data structures that *emulate* multidimensional arrays using pointers to rows or pointers to elements. Depending on how the data structure is defined, you can use the same `arr[x][y]` syntax to access the elements. Array indexing is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic, and in the common case where the prefix is the name of an array object, the name is implicitly converted to a pointer; if the prefix is already a pointer no conversion is done.

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

(In C++, it's generally easier to use container classes rather than C-style arrays.)